# What is the best way to reference resource identifiers in UIAutomator tests?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-uiautomator

I recently started using UIautomator for testing of my Android apps.

The following code fragment shows a typical statement within the code of the test cases:

```
mDevice.findObject(By.res(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE, "editTextUserInput"))
                .setText(STRING_TO_BE_TYPED);
```

As you can see, the "editTExtUserInput" is referenced as a string. In my applications source code this is defined as a resource identifier (R.id.editTextUserInput).

In the current situation, when I will change the name of the identifier in my app, all my test cases would get messed up (I will have to change all string values by hand)... Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: Have you thought about switching to [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html)? It is much, much easier to work with than UIAutomator for single app UI testing.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the Espresso framework. From the first looks this indeed seems a better approach for my tests.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Much of Google's Android Testing team has been spending time building [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html), a new UI testing framework which specifically makes these cases easier. For example, the line could be

```
onView(withId(R.id.editTextUserInput)).typeText(STRING_TO_BE_TYPED);
```

And things like identifier autocomplete and refactoring would also affect these tests.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Sometimes it's not possible to use Espresso and we still have to rely on UiAutomator. I hope someone out there can figure this out

Comment: Espresso does not work for all cases. This is question is related to UiAutomator.

Comment: @sid_09 - no, this question is about testing a String within your own UI, which is most definitely something you should be doing with Espresso. If the question had been about something that required UIAutomator (like cross app integration tests), then that would be a different question and a different answer.